# how to change xampp localhost to another domain on mac

Tags: macos, xampp, localhost

I searched a lot but there is no answer for how to change xampp localhost domain to another domain on mac..I've done it in windows before and it was easy but on mac not at all.
this how I try to do it:[picture of hosts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5eO0.png)

and then I changed vhosts.conf by adding new domain's details too:[picture of vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSr39.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you did it by the `hosts` file in windows you can edit `/etc/hosts` on mac. Add a line with the code `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com`. After that restart your mac and try to connect to `mydomain.com`. It might not work on some browsers, because they have an option named **DNS over HTTPS.** On firefox you can disable it by going to `Menu->Options->General->Network Settings->Settings` and disabling it.